# Convert a character string to the same type as another object

Tags: r

I have a character string, and I want to convert it to the same type as another object. You can assume this object is a vector. For example, given a string `"50"`, and a target vector `1:10`, I want `"50"` to be converted to an integer `50`. I wonder if there is a generic way to do the conversion. It is simple if I know which type I want to convert it to, e.g. I can use `as.numeric()` if I want it to be a number.

The background of this question is: I want to provide a graphical user interface so users can edit a value in a table. After they edit a cell, I will get a character string, and I know the original data (typically a matrix or a data frame). I want to update the original data with this new value. I cannot simply do `data[i, j] <- value` because `value` is a character string.

I could enumerate a few most common types (e.g. numeric, character, factor, date, ...) and use `as.*()` to do the conversion, but I'd prefer not to go this way if there is an existing generic approach. Things can be a little tricky for dates (timezone, origin) and factors (may add a new level).

Comment: This probably fails in some cases, but maybe `mode(obj1) <- mode(obj2)` or `class(obj1) <- class(obj2)`. where obj1 is user input and obj2 is the object to be modified.

Comment: `mode<-` is also what came to my mind first, but it won't work for factors or dates.

Comment: `class<-` works with dates (at least `class(obj1) <- class(as.Date("2001-10-10"))`) works. Maybe some branching between `mode<-`  and `class<-` depending on the type of object to be modified?

Answer (score 2):

(You might have found a way to solve this by now, but I'd have a try anyway...)

I checked the R documentation, and found that `base::as(object, Class)` is the generic way to do so. However, the default coercion methods are limited, and currently there is no default method to coerce Character class to Date class, nor for Factor class (you could check all the existing methods by `methods::showMethods("coerce"`). However, you could set customised methods with `methods::setAs()`, which is beyond my ability.

With my limited programming knowledge, I would probably use the following way to handle this problem:

```
assign_target_class = function (input_vector, target_vector){
    is.date = function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')
    if (is.date(target_vector)) {vector_class <- 'Date'}
    else if (base::is.factor(target_vector)) {vector_class <- 'Factor'}
    else {vector_class <- class(target_vector)}
    input_vector = as(input_vector, vector_class)
    input_vector
  }
```

P.S. if the date variable of the target vector is not set as Date yet, we could replace `is.date` with this argument instead:

```
is.convertible.to.date <- function(x) !is.na(as.Date(as.character(x), 
    tz = 'UTC', format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but `as(*, 'Date')` and `as(*, 'Factor')` won't really work.

Comment: Any way to make those work?